# Sending huge amount of data - java solutions

Tags: java, android, api, network-programming, data-transfer

I am currently looking for solutions for sending huge amount of data within a wireless network. This should be done using java and should also be able to run with Android.

The data to be sent is only text, but it should be able to handle a lot of packages being sent.
The data is to be sent from and to different android devices (phones and tablets) over a local network.

Until now, I came across the following "tools"/api:

- remote method invocations:
  http://download.java.net/jdk7u8/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/
- FDT: [monalisa.cern.ch/FDT/](http://monalisa.cern.ch/FDT/), https://fast-data-transfer.github.io/
- fastmpj: http://torusware.com/product/fastmpj/

But obviously I dont want to develope my own data transfer protocol/tool if what I need already exists.

So my question is:
Does some of you have expereince or can recommend some great tools/api's for this purpose?
(The perfomance is of course my first priority, but the more simple they are to use, the better)

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Where is the data going to and where is the data coming from?

Comment: this is a very broad question,  how much data, what kind if data, can it be paged, what constraints, what clients, which servers etc etc etc

Comment: Thanks for your input. sorry if the question was too broad. I'm editing the question now.

Comment: I certainly wouldn't use RMI for sending huge amounts of data. It's an OO RPC protocol. I would use FTP, FTP, or FTP.

Comment: Also if the data to be sent is text? And the amount is not "a lot". It should be able to handle a lot of smaller/medium packages being sent around the local network. I can't say how many packages will be sent, but it should be as scalable as possible.

Comment: * The amount of data of each transfer is not a lot, but the amount of packages being sent may be big.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems here:

1. The sheer volume of data.
2. Handling disconnections without having to resend all the data from scratch.

The volume can be helped by using compression. Core Java has compression libraries built in that will allow you to zip the data before sending and unzip it on arrival.

Disconnections is harder as you need to resume where you left off. There are a number of ways to do that involving either custom protocols or by using existing ones such as bittorrent.

Using bittorrent would also allow you to peer-to-peer the transmission if you have identical data going to massive numbers of users and are not too worried about privacy/security of the data.